# Logic for building converter using python dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary, converters

I have such slice of loaded json tp python dictionary (size_dict):

```
{
 "sizeOptionName":"XS",
 "sizeOptionId":"1528",
 "sortOrderNumber":"7017"
},
{
"sizeOptionName":"S",
"sizeOptionId":"1529",
"sortOrderNumber":"7047"
},
{
"sizeOptionName":"M",
"sizeOptionId":"1530",
"sortOrderNumber":"7095"
}
```

and I have products with size Id (dictionary_prod):

```
{
"catalogItemId":"7627712",
"catalogItemTypeId":"3",
"regularPrice":"0.0",
"sizeDimension1Id":"1528",
"sizeDimension2Id":"0",
}
```

I need to make such as output for any product:

```
 result_dict = {'variant':
 [{"catalogItemId":"7627712", ...some other info...,
 'sizeName': 'XS', 'sizeId': '1525'}}]}
```

so I need to convert size ID and add it to new result object

What is the best pythonic way to do this? 
I dont know how to get right data from size_dict

```
    if int(dictionary_prod['sizeDimension1Id']) > o:
        (result_dict['variant']).append('sizeName': size_dict???)
```

Comment: `size_dict` is not a dictionary; it is a list.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, i know, its just misspell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tommy mentioned, this is best facilitated by mapping the size id's to their respective dictionaries.

```
size_dict = \
[
    {
         "sizeOptionName":"XS",
         "sizeOptionId":"1528",
         "sortOrderNumber":"7017"
    },
    {
        "sizeOptionName":"S",
        "sizeOptionId":"1529",
        "sortOrderNumber":"7047"
    },
    {
        "sizeOptionName":"M",
        "sizeOptionId":"1530",
        "sortOrderNumber":"7095"
    }
]

size_id_map = {size["sizeOptionId"] : size for size in size_dict}

production_dict = \
[
    {
        "catalogItemId":"7627712",
        "catalogItemTypeId":"3",
        "regularPrice":"0.0",
        "sizeDimension1Id":"1528",
        "sizeDimension2Id":"0",
    }
]

def make_variant(idict):
    odict =  idict.copy()
    size_id = odict.pop("sizeDimension1Id")
    odict.pop("sizeDimension2Id")
    odict["sizeName"] = size_id_map[size_id]["sizeOptionName"]
    odict["sizeId"]   = size_id
    return odict

result_dict = \
{
    "variant" : [make_variant(product) for product in production_dict]
}

print(result_dict)
```

Comment: you are using .pop for prevent duplicates creation?

Comment: but what if i need to store sizeDimension2Id too?

Comment: It's quite simple. You'd store size2 in a variable, like is being done with size1, and use it to lookup in the map for its nice name. I'm going to leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: i`m doing as you have said, but keys for 2 sizes doesnt found, its kind wierd, cause can see them in debug...

Comment: You need to look at your data to see if `sizeDimension2Id` is consistently used.

Comment: why you are doing odict.pop("sizeDimension2Id") here? cant understand.. do i need this for getting sizeDimension1Id and sizeDimension2Id, thanks

Comment: and one more please: i have situations when size_dict can be dict, i need to do some if else for mapping:             if type(sizes2_dict) == list:
                size2_id_map = {size['sizeOptionId']: size for size in sizes2_dict}
            else:
                size2_id_map = {sizes2_dict['sizeOptionId']: sizes2_dict['sizeOptionName']}
but it doesnt help can you check size2_id_map = {sizes2_dict['sizeOptionId']: sizes2_dict['sizeOptionName']} is it written right? thanks

Comment: hi! i cant roll out this, there are a lot of possibilities that incoming object is dict

Comment: @user3275828, posting code in comments isn't workable; it's too difficult to read. Post a new question if you have further queries.

Comment: i know, my questions are deleted cause this question is similar

Comment: Yes, there is a paranoia about duplicate questions. Don't tag as `python` and it will likely be undisturbed (but also unnoticed).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing but it looks like you have a list (size_dict) of dictionaries that contain some infroamtion and you want to do a lookup to find a particular element in the list that contains the SizeOptionName you are interested in so that you can read off the SizeOptionID.

So first you could organsie your size_dict as a dictionary rather than a list - i.e.

```
    sizeDict = {"XS":{
     "sizeOptionName":"XS",
     "sizeOptionId":"1528",
     "sortOrderNumber":"7017"
    }, "S": {
    "sizeOptionName":"S",
    "sizeOptionId":"1529",
    "sortOrderNumber":"7047"
    }, ...
```

You could then read off the SizeOptionID you need by doing:

```
    sizeDict[sizeNameYouAreLookingFor][SizeOptionID]
```

Alternative you could keep your current structure and just search the list of dictionaries that is size_dict.

So:

```
    for elem in size_dict:
        if elem.SizeOptionID == sizeYouAreLookingFor:
            OptionID = elem.SizeOptionId
```

Or perhaps you are asking something else?